# Node.JS export function without object wrapper

Tags: function, module, node.js, export

I am looking at [Node.JS request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and notice that you can use

```
var request = require('request');
request(...)
```

But when I try to do something similar like in the module I try

```
exports = function() {}
```

it does not work. The only way I know to use is

```
var request = require('request').request;
request(...)
```

and

```
exports.request = function() {}
```

How can I set the whole export to a function instead of adding a function to the export object?

A hint might be available in the [request source code](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/8bb7f98ba8b78c217552c979811c07f1299318fe/main.js#L320-361) but I am finding it hard to figure out what is going on. Can you help?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to overwrite it as

`module.exports = function() {}`

Merely writing `exports = function() {}` creates a new local variables called exports and hides the `exports` variable living in `module.exports`